# How to add a % symbol in Pandas Styler Object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a % symbol into my columns after changing the percentages into int and applymap to them. Now I wanted to add the symbol back to the column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'CPU': ['80%', '60%', '90%'],
        'Memory': ['90%', '70%', '60%'],
        'MARKING': [1, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert percentage strings to decimals for calculations
df[['CPU', 'Memory']] = df[['CPU', 'Memory']].replace('%', '', regex=True).astype(int)


def highlight_cells(val, threshold):
    if val > threshold:
        return 'color: red'
    return ''


def highlight_row(row):
    if row['MARKING'] == 1:
        return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)
    return [''] * len(row)


styled_df = (df.style.applymap(lambda x: highlight_cells(x, 35), subset=['CPU'])
             .applymap(lambda x: highlight_cells(x, 38), subset=['Memory']))
styled_df = styled_df.apply(highlight_row, axis=1)

# Save styled output with original percentage strings
with pd.ExcelWriter('styled_output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    styled_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Styled', index=False)
```

Here is the error I had faced when I added this code `styled_df['CPU', 'Memory'] = styled_df['CPU', 'Memory'] + '%'` to add the percentage back to the code.
Error: `TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this question. Just declare a new variable that remove the % and compare with the threshold.

```
def highlight_cells(val, threshold):
    v = int(val.replace('%', ''))
    if v > threshold:
        return 'color: red'
    return ''
```